# Search in a Column

Tags: android, database

my database:

```
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text,EMAIL text,SECURITYHINT text); ";
```

my searching:

```
public Cursor searchDB(String query) { 
        return db.query("LOGIN",
                  new String[] { "SECURITYHINT" },
                  "SECURITYHINT"+" LIKE '%" + query+"%'", null, null, null, null);           
    }
```

and in signup.java:

```
/*
           if( loginDataBaseAdapter.searchDB(secuhint) != null){<br>
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "securityhint exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return;  
           }    */
```

So i'd like to check that there are exists the security hint what the user write, may be i think the method calling can be a problem...can somebody help me?

Comment: you have to check if Cursor has row and close it ...

Answer (score -1):

You can also you use a `rawQuery` like this:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE SECURITYHUNT ='" + query + "'", null);
```

Comment: and? how it will help?